# jQuery focusout() with text field and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field with Typeahead autocomplete. Users should be able to type in manually or choose from select list. 
Before the user can submit the form I already want to validate what the user has entered in the text field. This is working with AJAX already.

The jQuery trigger is focusout(), but seems to be triggered in that moment when the user chooses something from the autocomplete list. So if the user chooses from autocomplete, the error-message mistakenly appears.

```
$('#category-autocomplete-field').focusout(function(){
                if($(this).val() != '')
                {
                    let categoryName = $(this).val();
                    let language = "en";
                    let _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"{{ route('category.checkIfExists') }}",
                        method:"GET",
                        data:{
                            categoryName: categoryName,
                            language: language,
                            _token:_token,
                        },
                        success:function(result)
                        {
                            if(result !== 'exists') {
                                $('#autcomplete-validation-message').html(
                                    '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' +
                                    'This category does not exist. ' +
                                    '</div>')
                            } else{
                                $('#autcomplete-validation-message').html('');
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(data) {
                            console.log(data.responseText)
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try `.keyup()` instead : https://api.jquery.com/keyup/#keyup-handler

Comment: Why not .change() (https://api.jquery.com/change/) ?